# Is building a corporation a good option?

Tags: united-states, corporation

In Robert Kiyosaki's "[Rich Dad, Poor Dad](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1612680011)" he talks about building a corporation and doing transaction through it instead of doing them yourself, directly. There seems to be a lot of advantages in doing this like paying less taxes and reduced liability. This seems to be a wonderful idea but I don't understand what are the disadvantages.

Can anyone explain why creating a corporation can be a bad practice?

Comment: IRS, IRS, IRS and the torture they heap on you when they want to investigate !!

Comment: +1, from second hand experinces (people hired "tax consultants" who got them back a lot of money in refunds but disappeared when IRS followed up)

Comment: Whether it is good or bad practice likely has much to do with the *function* of the corporation. What kinds of business will the corporation be doing? More details may get you better answers.

Answer (score 12):

Creating a corporation is not necessarily less taxes. In fact, you'll face the problem of [double taxation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_taxation), and since you must pay yourself a *reasonable* salary, if your corporation doesn't earn much to give you as dividend after the salary, and/or your tax bracket is low, you'll in fact may end up paying more taxes. Also there's a lot of bureaucracy involved in managing a corporation.

Liability on the other hand is important, and what's more important - is asset separation and limiting the liability to the corporation assets, keeping your personal assets safe. To achieve that, you don't have to create a corporation, but you can create a Limited Liability Company (LLC). LLC are disregarded entities for tax purposes (i.e.: you won't have to pay taxes twice, only once as a sole proprietor/partner), but provide the liability limitation and asset separation. LLC's are much less formal, and require much less paperwork reducing the risk of [corporate veil piercing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piercing_the_corporate_veil) because of non-compliance.

I myself [decided to manage my investments through LLC](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/12012/would-it-make-sense-to-buy-a-rental-property-as-an-llc-and-not-in-my-own-name)'s for that very reason (asset separation).

Comment: Excellent answer, well worth my +1.

Comment: This might be besides the point, but would you recommend anyone actually follow Robert Kiyosaki's "advice"? I do read his books, but just for entertainment and as fodder for evenings at the pub.

Comment: @f1StudentInUS I have no idea who he is and never read his books, but usually most of the books on the topic "how to become a millionaire" can be summarized in one sentence: "sell a million books on the topic of how to become a millionaire".

Comment: Pardon my DV, but your first paragraph has some incorrect information. Double taxation only applies to C-Corps, not S-Corps. On the other hand, Reasonable Salary only applies to S-Corps, not C-Corps. With an S-Corp, I don't think it's possible to pay more in taxes than you would without it.

Comment: @littleadv - "sell a million books" - so true! Apparently it's sold 26 million copies: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Dad_Poor_Dad

Comment: @TTT both of your statements are incorrect. Reasonable salary requirement is for **any** corporation, the difference is in the consequences. For C corporations, it is actually advised to take as much as possible as salary, while for S - as little as possible. In both cases this opposite behavior leads to reduced taxes. However, both may end up being characterized as tax evasion by the IRS and the definition of "reasonable" is not well defined and can be challenged - in both cases. Dual taxation exists for S-Corps on State level in some States, and there are limits on what and how S can do.

Comment: @littleadv - OK, I didn't know that in C-Corps you could be dinged for paying too much salary. I concede I was wrong about that though I don't think that would come into play for someone weighing sole proprietorship vs corp (though it is possible in theory). I still wouldn't say double taxation is an issue for S-Corps, at least not in general. When it is it's certainly an edge case, as very few jurisdictions have a tax on S-Corp earnings that are higher than FICA taxes. (CA and IL tax only 1.5%, NY is even less but NYC is an outlier and taxes 8.85%.)

Answer (score 1):

Compared with a Sole Proprietorship, the main disadvantages of an S-Corporation or an LLC are that it adds a lot of management overhead (time, and possibly money if you don't do it all yourself), and there are fees you must pay to incorporate, as well as additional yearly maintenance fees which vary by state. You should be able to weigh the tax savings and liability protection against the extra costs and hassle, and see which way the scales tip. As a rule of thumb, the bigger your business gets or the more income you make, the more attractive incorporating becomes.

Note there are some additional taxes that certain jurisdictions impose on business income. For example, IL and CA charge 1.5% tax, NY is less, but NYC is 8.85%! In NYC specifically, you could actually end up paying slightly more tax as an S-Corp than you would as a Sole Proprietorship. In most places though, the nominal local taxes will still be less than the FICA taxes you could potentially save.

Comment: Would the DVer care to comment so I can improve my answer?

Comment: they rarely do.  I've posted many answers that I think are good, and they get DV with no comment.  I think that SE should require a reason for a DV.

Comment: @MikeP - your suggestion gets made all the time on Meta, and although it's possible the majority of people agree with you, it will likely never happen because of the belief that allowing anonymous DVs is more important than the integrity of a DV. I once floated the idea of the price to DV with a comment is -1, and the price to DV anonymously is more costly than that (perhaps in the -2 to -5 range), but it didn't gain any traction.